# Token to name eval'ed javascript

Tags: javascript, eval, google-chrome-devtools

I remember seeing this in a Paul Irish video - I've even used this a handful of times, though not often enough to memorize.

There is some token something similar to `//@ someName` that you can append to an eval'ed script to have chrome assign it a name in devtools (so that it can be debugged).

What exactly is that token?

Comment: @zerkms - no, this is not a part of javascript - it's just a token that can be placed in a comment that devtools recognizes

Comment: but you still can debug it with `debugger;` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//@ sourceURL=dynamicScript.js
```

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints?hl=de-DE

Googled using "chrome dev tools eval name" request